# Flex: ActionScript Project Size Problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, size

I have some interesting problem for an hour.. In my flex project, all width and height properties returns as zero.. i tried this :

```
    private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        trace(stage.width, parent.width, this.width, root.width);
    }
```

and results :

0 0 0 0

using Flex, sdk 3.2

Anybody could help me?

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want stage.stageWidth, and stage.stageHeight, not stage.width, and stage.height.

Comment: OMG! how i missed this.. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried the stage.stageHeight I set it to 100 but in the trace it still gives me 950